# NGINX brew install command not found

Tags: command-line, nginx, homebrew, bash

I do

```
$ brew install nginx
```

and get:

```
==> Downloading http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/nginx-1.2.2.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file conf/nginx.conf
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.2 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre         --with-ipv6 --with-cc-opt=-I/usr/local/include --with-ld-opt=-L/usr/local/lib --conf
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
In the interest of allowing you to run `nginx` without `sudo`, the default
port is set to localhost:8080.

If you want to host pages on your local machine to the public, you should 
change that to localhost:80, and run `sudo nginx`. You'll need to turn off
any other web servers running port 80, of course.

You can start nginx automatically on login running as your user with:
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.2/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist

Though note that if running as your user, the launch agent will fail if you
try to use a port below 1024 (such as http's default of 80.)
Warning: /usr/local/sbin is not in your PATH
You can amend this by altering your ~/.bashrc file
```

I have this in my ~/.bashrc file:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

When I run nginx -v or sudo nginx -t i get this:

```
-bash: nginx: command not found
```

have I not installed nginx properly?

Comment: When you run `echo $PATH`, does /usr/local/sbin appear?

Comment: Try sourcing your ~/.bashrc file and see if it appears: `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Nothing should appear, but your `$PATH` variable should be updated. Try `echo $PATH` again =) . If it didn't work, there might be a problem with your .bashrc

Comment: This was appended to what I received previously
:/Users/macuser/usr/local/sbin:/Users/macuser/.rvm/bin:/Users/macuser/usr/local/sbin

Comment: I find it weird that it's prepending '/Users/macuser' to the path you're trying to export. Maybe that's the problem, but I don't know how to help you =(

Comment: Thanks!! that was the issue. While I was trying different things I had changed it to "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/sbin". I just had to remove "$HOME". I changed it back, ran source ~/.bashrc. Now the Nginx command is working :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run echo $PATH, does /usr/local/sbin appear?
if not: 
Try sourcing your ~/.bashrc file and see if it appears: source ~/.bashrc

run echo $PATH again. It should apear.

Answer (score 1):

I just install nginx by brewHome, and I find the path is `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.0/bin`, so I just add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.0/bin` to the conf file, and it works well.

FYI

Answer (score 0):

In my debian 6 server nginx is installed in `/usr/sbin/` . If you want to access it directly from terminal add that directory to your PATH variable:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin/:$PATH
```

The `sbin` directories are commonly added to PATH for the root user, are you logged in the terminal as root ? If not you can do so by entering `su` command.

Comment: If installed by Homebrew, it'll be in `/usr/local/sbin`.