# sudo nginx -t password issue

Tags: macos, nginx, terminal, sudo

I installed nginx, and when I run the following command...

```
sudo nginx -t
```

I get the following

```
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: nginx: command not found
```

I don't remember ever setting a password and ran through the ones I would have used.  Is there a way to find out what password to use or reset it?

Comment: Can you specify the OS, your `/etc/sudoers` and the current user that  try to use sudo ?

Comment: using mac osx.  when i use visudo in terminal, I get the following... visudo: /private/etc/sudoers: Permission denied, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: so far, more people editing comments than posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` uses your login password. In the snippet above, you got it right the second time around.

The error `sudo: nginx: command not found` indicates that nginx is either not installed, or not installed where you think it is.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but even commands like sudo apt-get nginx or any sudo commends don't seem to work

Comment: `apt-get` is a Debian Linux command. It does not exist on Mac OS X.

Comment: you were right, it wasn't installing because of a path error.  turned out that this was the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713233/nginx-brew-install-command-not-found